how to optimize a fetch in react native expo
I work at an application with react native and expo. After I login the user I call an request for getting user data. The app needs to work offline and when the user has connection I make the request and save the date in a sqlite data base. The problem it s the data is big and it blocks the entire app. For fetch I create an hook like this:
import { FetchResponse } from "@/models/Fetch/FetchResponse";
import useRequest from "./useRequest";
import { fetchEndpoints } from "@/models/Fetch/fetchEndpoints";
import { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import useTranslation from "./useTranslation";
import { Toast } from "toastify-react-native";
import { useIsConnected } from "./useIsConnected";
import { processItems } from "@/services/processItems";

export const useBackgroundFetch = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const isConnected = useIsConnected();
  const { request } = useRequest<FetchResponse>({
    url: fetchEndpoints.fetch,
    method: "GET",
    onSuccess: async (data) => {
      const { items } = data;
      await processItems(items);
    },
  });

  const makeRequestIfConnected = useCallback(() => {
    if (isConnected) {
      console.log("Making request");
      request();
      return;
    }

    Toast.error(t("info.offlineMode"), "top");
  }, [isConnected]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      console.log("Network state: ", isConnected);
      //   return;
      console.log("Registering background fetch");
      makeRequestIfConnected();
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        makeRequestIfConnected();
      }, 1000 * 60 * 15);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [isConnected]);
};

the data needs to be updated at a regular time when the user has internet connection. How to optimise this code ?
Thanks!

Split data into smaller chunks.
